# php while loop with array replace json output

Tags: php, json, sql-server, xamarin.forms

My php code as follows

```
<?php

require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/connectionInfoTestNew.php');


$connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
$connectionInfo->GetConnection();

if (!$connectionInfo->conn)
{
    //Connection failed
    echo 'No Connection';
}

else
{

    $query = 'select DISTINCT i.tabledetailid as tabledetailid, i.name as name, c.tabledetailid as tableDet from tabledetail i left join temporderdetail c on i.tabledetailid = c.tabledetailid';

    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($connectionInfo->conn, $query);

    if (!$stmt)
    {
        //Query failed
        echo 'Query failed';
    }

    else
    {
        $contacts = array(); //Create an array to hold all of the contacts

        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) //While there are still contacts
        {               
            //the names must match exactly the property names in the contact class in our C# code.
            $contact= array("ID" => $row['tabledetailid'],
                             "Name" => $row['name'],
                             "tableDet" => $row['tableDet']);

            //Add the contact to the contacts array
            array_push($contacts, $contact);
        }

        //Echo out the contacts array in JSON format
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        $output = ['TableInfo' => $contacts];
        echo json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
}?>
```

and the output as follows

```
{
"TableInfo": [
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "Name": "TABLE 01",
        "tableDet": "1"
    },
    {
        "ID": "2",
        "Name": "TABLE 02",
        "tableDet": "2"
    },
    {
        "ID": "3",
        "Name": "TABLE 03",
        "tableDet": null
    },
    {
        "ID": "4",
        "Name": "TABLE 04",
        "tableDet": null
    },
    {
        "ID": "5",
        "Name": "TABLE 05",
        "tableDet": "5"
    },
    {
        "ID": "6",
        "Name": "TABLE 06",
        "tableDet": null
    },
    {
        "ID": "7",
        "Name": "TABLE 07",
        "tableDet": null
    },
    {
        "ID": "8",
        "Name": "TABLE 08",
        "tableDet": "8"
    },
    {
        "ID": "9",
        "Name": "TABLE 09",
        "tableDet": "9"
    },
    {
        "ID": "10",
        "Name": "TABLE 10",
        "tableDet": null
    },
    {
        "ID": "11",
        "Name": "TABLE 11",
        "tableDet": null
    },
    {
        "ID": "12",
        "Name": "TABLE 12",
        "tableDet": null
    },
    {
        "ID": "13",
        "Name": "TABLE 13",
        "tableDet": null
    },
    {
        "ID": "14",
        "Name": "TABLE 14",
        "tableDet": null
    },
    {
        "ID": "15",
        "Name": "TABLE 15",
        "tableDet": null
    },
    {
        "ID": "16",
        "Name": "TABLE 01",
        "tableDet": null
    }
]}
```

what my expectation is that to replace the  "tableDet": "2" and "tableDet": "3" Etc.....  as  "tableDet": "Occupied" example expecting output mention below

```
{
"TableInfo": [
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "Name": "TABLE 01",
        "tableDet": "occupied"
    },
    {
        "ID": "2",
        "Name": "TABLE 02",
        "tableDet": "occupied"
    },
    {
        "ID": "3",
        "Name": "TABLE 03",
        "tableDet": null
    },
    {
        "ID": "4",
        "Name": "TABLE 04",
        "tableDet": null
    },
    {
        "ID": "5",
        "Name": "TABLE 05",
        "tableDet": "occupied"
    }]}
```

so how should i replace the number output ( 1,2,3,etc) to the string output("occupied") in the php code ? , thank you in-advance for your support

Comment: Replace `"tableDet" => $row['tableDet']` by `"tableDet" => (isset($row['tableDet']) ? 'occupied' : NULL)`.

Comment: Thank you so much its working perfectly

Comment: That's good. Perhaps I should have explained that the `... ? ... : ...` is called a *ternary operator*, see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Comment: Thank you the link was really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this inside the loop:

```
if(isset($row['tableDet'])){// or !is_null() or is_numeric()
$tableDet = "occupied"; 
}else{
$tableDet = $row['tableDet']);//or = "free" or null
}
$contact= array(
     "ID" => $row['tabledetailid'],
      "Name" => $row['name'],
      "tableDet" => $tableDet);
```